# Как отправлять запрос в активное соединение с вебсокетом

Tags: python, сокет, websocket, асинхронность, asyncio

Не могу правильно выстроить архитектуру из 2 функциями.
Суть заключется в том чтоб функция **A** держала открытым соединение с вебсокетом и ждала ответов, а функция **Б** при ее вызове **в другом файле** отправляла запрос в вебсокет, который инициализирован в функции **А**

Примерно так это выглядит в моем коде:

```
import asyncio 
import websockets 
import json

ws = websockets.connect("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv") 

async def main_loop(ws):
    print("Successfully connected")
    while True:
        response = await ws.recv()
        if response is None:
            continue 
        else:
            data = json.loads(response)

async def add_wallet(ws, address):
    await ws.send('{"op":"addr_sub", "addr":"%s"}' % wallet)
    print("Successfully subscribed to %s" % wallet)
```

Однако мне кажется что такая архитектура является неверной, да и из-за асинхронности так просто это не выполнишь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как есть `await` `while True:` не блокирует loop.

Тогда после подключения запускайте читалку как фоновое задание:

```
reader = asyncio.ensure_future(main_loop(ws), loop=loop)
```

Сохраните `reader` в классе или в global чтоб его не сожрал GC.
Дальше можно свободно пользоваться  `ws.send(...)`